# Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BitMap_1); // <--This is not allowed? How

Tags: c#

Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BitMap_1); // <--This is not allowed? How can I fix it?How can I declare graphics as global?
Here is some more code...
Here is some more code...
Here is some more code...
Here is some more code...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string WAV_filePath  = @"";
    string MIDI_filePath = @"";
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\Steffan\Desktop\guitar\Gert toets die Elektroniese Konsertina.wav";//Guitar 2.wav";//Sine Wave 440Hz.wav";
    SoundPlayer player1 = new SoundPlayer();
    byte[] RawWaveDataArray = new byte[100];
    Int16[] Data_16Bit = new Int16[100];
    int NumberOfSamples = 0;
    bool PLAY_ = false;
    Point[] Points = new Point[886];
    // Create pen.
    Pen Pen_ = new Pen(Color.White, 0);
    Bitmap BitMap_1 = new Bitmap(1138, 72);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BitMap_1); // <--This is not allowed? How can I fix it?How can I declare graphics as global?

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PLAY_ == true)
        {
            Wave_x_Inc = 0;
            graphics.Clear(Color.Black);
            for (int x = 0; x < 886; x++)
            {
                Points[x]  = new Point(Wave_x_Inc, (int)((Data_16Bit[DataIndex] * 0.002F) + (pictureBox4.Height / 2)));
                Wave_x_Inc = Wave_x_Inc + 2;

                DataIndex = DataIndex + 2;
                if (DataIndex > Data_16Bit.Length/2) { DataIndex = 0; x = 886; }
            }

            if (Wave_x_Inc > pictureBox4.Width) { Wave_x_Inc = 0; }

            graphics.DrawBeziers(Pen_, Points);

            WaveLengthCounter = WaveLengthCounter + 886;

            int Temp_Val = WaveLengthCounter / DataLenth_Fraction;

            if (Temp_Val <= 300) { trackBar1.Value = Temp_Val; }
            else { trackBar1.Value = 0; }

            if (WaveLengthCounter > Data_16Bit.Length/2)
            {
                WaveLengthCounter = 0;
            }
            pictureBox4.Image = BitMap_1;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you show the whole method you have to draw the curve? That may help people answer your question a little more fully

Comment: can you post more codes of your application events an methods ?

Comment: Can't you do it the same way you did for "Bitmap b" ?

Comment: Whatever really happens, the creation of the Graphics object is certainly not the bottleneck! But of course you __could__ declare it as type Graphics, just where you declared the Bitmap.. - Also: do tell us more about what you really want to do. Maybe we can advise you to a totally different solution, maybe involving the Paint event..

Comment: If you are trying to create an animation at 50 frames/sec using GDI+ you may be in for a surprise...

Comment: I added some more code...

Comment: Ok, this helps. I suggest you 1) rewrite the code to draw in the `Paint` event using its `e.Grahpics` object. 2) call `pictureBox4.Invalidate` in the tick event. 3) don't event try to draw faster than the human eye can see, ie 16Hz.  4) forget about the `Image` of the PB for this kind of usage!  - Note that GDI+ takes some time to master. (And even then is not very good for any animation..) good luck..

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it may help you.

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 10, 10);

bitmap.Save("MyShapes.png");
```

Comment: How does this even come close to answering the question, and what is the blatant "follow me" thing about? This seems more like spam than an answer.

Comment: Answers are not the place to advertise yourself; that's what your user profile is for.